# Does Firefox 41 have a bug when formatting `new Intl.NumberFormat("es-ES").format(3500)` as `3 500`?

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-intl

When trying to become familiar with the support of number formatting in the different browsers I found that Firefox 41 formats `new Intl.NumberFormat("es-ES").format(3500)` as `3 500` (with a space as the group separator) while IE 11, Edge and Google Chrome give me `3.500` (with a dot `.` as the group separator).

I am wondering, is that a bug in Firefox? Or is the number format allowed in Spanish in Spain ambiguous?

```js
var d1 = 3500;
var esES = new Intl.NumberFormat("es-ES");
var formattedNumber = esES.format(d1);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<p>Formatted the number ' + d1 + ' with NumberFormat ' + esES.resolvedOptions().locale + ' as ' + formattedNumber + '<\/p>');
```

Comment: It's a very uncommon format here in Spain. I particularly only use it (if ever) in hand-written notes. Thousand separator is `.`.

Comment: In Chrome 86, numbers < 10000 which are formatted in Spanish no longer have the thousand separator. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1139358

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried a Firefox nightly and it returns `3.500` instead of `3 500`. Then I searched bugzilla and it looks as there have been various bug reports related to number formatting with locale "es-ES", like https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1013091 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1078154 which have been resolved as fixed. So it looks like the issue was regarded as a bug but it has already been fixed in the nightlies/development versions of Firefox.

Comment: I can confirm it's fixed on Firefox/42.0

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'd say it's ambiguous. Citing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping:

> *Typically, [non-English-speaking] European countries employ periods or spaces: 10.000 or 10 000.*

I'm not Spanish, but as a continental European I can confirm that both are equally common and well-understood<sup>1</sup>. Just don't use a comma, which is the decimal separator<sup>2</sup>. Personally I prefer a thin space.

<sub>1: Wikipedia also lists "Spain" in multiple places in their [*Examples* section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use)

2: This is different for Spanish as spoken in America though, see e.g. [Microsofts *Spanish Style Guide*](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/8/0/c80371fa-bc89-46a7-883d-071d59f0c24c/spa-esp-StyleGuide.pdf)</sub>

Comment: And when speaking of money, the amount can also be written as `1.200,-` or `1200,-` instead of using `1200,00`. With normal numbers I do see spaces very often, but when it's about money I rarely see spaces.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this spec, but does it not define the precise format? I doubt if this would be left up to the browser developer to implement based on their notion of locale standards.

Comment: @torazaburo: No, it is left to the implementation. It's not the responsibility of ECMA-402 to define a locale-to-formatting mapping. There a projects to standardise such, but they are supposed to change separately and be used elsewhere. As an example, ES only specifies the `Date` API, but it does not include the timezone database.